# How should I execute this idea?

Tags: creative-writing, technique, structure, planning, brainstorming

I'm writing a story. This story will be longer than a short story and shorter than a novel.

The story is of a hacker. He is at a stage in life where he wants to reflect therefore he writes his story of his dealings with cyber crimes.
While writing his story, he attains clarity about his own true self.

Would it be better to put the revelations at the end of his life story or to share that insight where the relevant text arises?

Reference for the Story: Ghost in the Wires: My Adventures as the World's Most Wanted Hacker
By Kevin Mitnick

Comment: Nothing is more boring than to witness a writer's selfinvolvedness.

Comment: @what: That depends. Say, the story is a crime story, and the writer discovers to be a perfectionist, incapable of committing to paper ideas he didn't try to work for real? ;)  Don't judge a book by its cover :)

Comment: @SF I wrote: "a writer's selfinvovedness", not "a writer committing a crime". The question here is about the story of a writer who through his writing attains clarity about his own true self. That is, it is about a writer experiencing himself through writing. That is a great topic for a self-help book that presents writing as a tool for personal development, but it is a boring topic for a novel. Much "high" literature is about writers writing, and I am bored to death by this circularity of writers writing about writers writing and how they feel when they write about writing etc.

Comment: @What The writer is also a hacker.His story about cyber crime.I think my edited version of the question is a better representation of what I am actually asking.

Comment: @what: 1. The asker didn't write what story does the protagonist write. I seriously hope he doesn't write a story about a writer discovering true self through writing a story about a writer discovering a true self through writing... - that would be too ironic. It may be as well the protagonist writes a crime story. 2. The motif of self-discovery all by itself is a worthless meta, a road, not a goal. Now WHAT is that self that has been discovered is what matters. So, if through self-discovery the writer discovers to be a murderous psychopath, and the characters died in real life? A great story!

Comment: @SF: I've edited the question to give more clarity.

Comment: Well, I do agree with Elemecca. If you remove all the good stuff from the middle and pack all in the end, the middle will be terribly bland, but leave something good for the end. Also, do make sure these revelations are worthwhile. There are few more disappointing endings than a boring, plain man discovering to be a boring, plain man.

Comment: It might work with some in the middle and a big one at the end. E.g. A person who has a definite impression of himself - as he writes small revelations occur culminating at the end with a dramatic synthesis that he is almost completely different from who he initially thought he was. This runs parallel to a major Eastern concept of enlightenment which entails (among other things) a dropping of all preconceptions and seeing things as they really are.

Comment: @Joe - How plausible would be the theme of a hacker gaining enlightenment via writing ?

Comment: @Joe - Would it be better if there were flashes of enlightenment which were not explicitly mentioned to be enlightenment to signify that such flashes occur in everybody's lives ?

Comment: Enlightenment as currently used covers a lot more than "true" enlightenment. Why is he/she "hacking"? Writing about that could lead to a re-evaluation of goals. Was it worth it? Was it done in service of the "right" cause? Did all that "hacking" really change who they are? Etc. Maybe "insight" would be better than "enlightenment". Or maybe they could merge with a machine, etc. to attain some sort of techno-enlightenment, if you can find a way to make it believable and not B-movie material.

Comment: Enlightenment with a "small e" ;) or even the real deal is demonstrated by actions (show, don't tell). The actions can also be realizations which are part of the story. What usually happens to people is that a large number of relatively small insights add up inconspicuously and at some point a sort of critical mass is reached where the person's overall outlook or actions change enough so that they notice that they have grown/changed. Often, it takes someone else to notice the changes because gradual change can seem like nothing is happening to the person changing....

Comment: Continued... Sometimes a major event can trigger a major internal change - like getting caught criminally hacking, being betrayed, or some other trauma. In any case, it would be much better for the reader to figure it out by seeing the effects of the changes/realizations rather than having them labelled as such by the author or by the protagonist.

Answer (score 2):

I would share the insight where relevant. It's no fun to leave all of the good stuff at the end. In my experience, writing is a journey, and we need to be privy to all aspects of it. This includes the vital balancing act between [flow](http://www.pursuit-of-happiness.org/history-of-happiness/mihaly-csikszentmihalyi/) and [insanity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insanity) inside the character's head.

Comment: especially if that's longer than a short story, the reader will be bored to death if you pick out all the juicy bits from the middle to leave them for dessert.

Comment: Keep in mind that some readers skip to the end and read it first.  So you'd better give them a reason to read the rest.

Comment: @dmm Heh -_- That was a joke, right?